# Ubuntu Java Postgresql JDBC

Tags: java, apache, postgresql, ubuntu, jdbc

How can I get Java to query a Postgresql server running on Ubuntu 16.04? I have downloaded postgresql-9.4.1212.jre6.jar (JDBC Driver), but I do not know what I am suppose to do with it...

```
java JDBCExample
Connecting to database...
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:27)
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your [class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). Change

```
java JDBCExample
```

to

```
java -cp .:postgresql-9.4.1212.jre6.jar JDBCExample
```